# MobileFirst 7.1 - PI77314 "UNKNOWN" VALUES ARE OBSERVED IN ANALYTICS CLIENT LOGS

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Since we deployed MobileFirst 7.1.0.0-MFPF-Server-IF201701200103 We were facing this "UNKNOWN" issue in Analytics. I have observed that this issue is fixed in the recent release. We will be deploying this latest release soon. My question is once we deploy this fix, how do we fix this incorrect entry in analytics. Since three months we are seen a lot of these entries.

Is there any way to update the data. Is there any kind of client or a client which can show us a table like structure that we can use to view update or delete data.

Answer (score 0):

The existing UNKNOWN entries in the Analytics Store cannot be eliminated. So having a proper TTL (Time To Live) Settings in place configured for analytics will clear up (purge) the old data will remove in course of time.